smoke domain issue
I am new to Blender and trying to make a smoke domain but I have a strange problem. The smoke is  not showing from frame 1 to frame 250, and it suddenly shows and instantly fills the domain at frame 251, but no fire is showing at all. I can't change the color of the smoke, etc. I followed some tutorials about cache on how to fix the problem and it is not solved yet. Here are some details: when I change the cache frame start to 0 and end to 1, the smoke doesn't show from 0 to 1 and shows elsewhere but it is just a sudden fixed smoke which I can't change its properties.

You may not be able to change it if you've baked the actions. Consider editing your post with screenshots of your problem so we are better equipped to help you. Also, you may need a texture for the fire to show up.

Thanks for your reply, the main issue is that the smoke domain runs outside the frame period of cache , in other words if the frames of cache are set from 1 to 250 , I'll not be able to see any smoke within that period and only see it outside it , an additional info , I used the fire and smoke effect before and it was great I don't know what happened

Sorry, but without any screenshots of your settings or even better the file itself there are too many possible causes.

the problem is that the file size is more than 39 mb given that its just a circle and smoke domain so am not able to upload it , i am so sorry but i am still a beginner

You can share large files with Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox or any other file hoster like https://wetransfer.com/ (does not require an account, just click on the 3 dots menu icon and choose the "link" instead of "mail"). Then post the link here.
